# Какова вероятность выбрав случайный ответ ответить правильно?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, теория-вероятностей

> Есть вопрос в тесте с четырьмя вариантами ответов:
>
> 1. 1/4
> 2. 1/3
> 3. 1/2
> 4. 1/4
>
> Какова вероятность выбрав случайный ответ ответить правильно?

Мои мысли:

Кажется, что выбрать один ответ из четырех - это `1/4`, но таких вариантов два, и тогда вероятность складывается и должно быть `1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2`, но такой вариант один из четырех, и тогда вероятность выбрать его снова `1/4`, какой-то замкнутый круг.

Comment: о_О Предполагаем, что среди указанных вариантов гарантированно имеется правильный ответ. Вариантов ответа - три. Правильный - один. Вероятность угадать = 1/3. Другое дело, что если правильный ответ 1/4, то вероятность угадать его - 2/4, а если правильный ответ 1/2 или 1/3, то вероятность угадать его всего 1/4.

Comment: Имею глупый вопрос: а проверяется номер ответа или содержание ответа? )  Обычно всё-таки если ответы пронумерованы, то содержимое ответов никто не проверяет, а проверяют, что был выбран правильный номерок. )  И очень странно, что у двух номерков одинаковое значение ответа.

Comment: @CrazyElf не уточнено, но я думаю, что содержание, иначе ответ 1/4 слишком очевиден)

Comment: мне кажется, нужно отдельно рассмотреть вероятность, когда правильный ответ-это 1/4, то есть ответ 1/2 и тот случай, когда правильный ответ не 1/4, тогда вероятность 1/3, так как разных ответов 3, то есть общая вероятность-это 1/2+1/3=5/6, но тогда вероятность угадать как-то слишком большая...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос в *вероятности правильного ответа*.

Если, например, заранее известно, что ответ 1/4, то вероятность 1/2 :)

Поэтому остается только сделать некоторое предположение о том, каким образом выбирается верный ответ. Простейший случай — все варианты равновероятны. Тогда согласно теорверу вероятность угадать равна 1/3*1/4+1/3*1/4+1/3*2/4 = 1/3.

Что вполне согласуется с вычислительным экспериментом :), типа

```
int main()
{
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 g(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<> d(0, 2);

    int total = 0, ok = 0;

    for(;;)
    {
        int i[4] = {1,0,0,0};
        if (d(g) == 0) i[1] = 1;
        shuffle(i,i+4,g);
        ++total;
        if (i[0]) ++ok;

        cout << double(ok)/total << "\r";
    }
}
```

Но вот если верные ответы **не** равновероятны, то все, что можно сказать — от 1/4 до 1/2...